# How do I change a row entry to "Unknown"?

Tags: r, casting, na

The column in the dataframe is a factor and has 8 levels. "" is included as a factor. I want to change "" to "Unknown"

```
df[df$VariantType == ""] <- "Unknown"
```

is producing an error

Do I have to cast to another data type?

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, i cannot reproduce this issue if the 'Unknown' is already a `level` in the column ; `df <- data.frame(Variant_type = c('', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'Unknown')); df[df$VariantType == ""] <- "Unknown"`

Comment: It is better you show a small example with `dput` i.e. `dput(droplevels(head(df$VariantType, 20)))`

Comment: I think @akrun has the right answer but has missed a comma. Try `df <- data.frame(Variant_type = c('', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'Unknown')); df[df$VariantType == "", ] <- "Unknown"`

Comment: I think you guys made some bad mistakes. First, you've assumed that the "unknown" level already exists in the data, which it doesn't since the OP clearly stated that the code didn't work. Second, why are you trying to update the whole data frame `df` and not the individual column `VariantType`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R is fussy when it comes to factor levels. You have to replace the *level(s)* with your new one(s).

```
df <- data.frame(id=1:3, VariantType=c("A","","B"))
str(df)
#'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ id         : int  1 2 3
# $ VariantType: Factor w/ 3 levels "","A","B": 2 1 3

df
#  id VariantType
#1  1           A
#2  2            
#3  3           B

levels(df$VariantType)
#[1] ""  "A" "B"
```

Now replace "" with "Unknown". You can do it manually using the index:

```
levels(df$VariantType)[1] <- "Unknown"
```

Or using a logical expression:

```
levels(df$VariantType)[levels(df$VariantType)==""] <- "Unknown"

df
#  id VariantType
#1  1           A
#2  2     Unknown
#3  3           B

levels(df$VariantType)
#[1] "Unknown" "A"       "B"
```

Comment: Thank you this worked.
I tried ```test1[test1$VariantType == ""] <- "Unknown" ``` but that didn't work. Next time I'll remember to assign to name by calling levels and index.

Comment: Your attempt to change the levels by changing the data doesn't work because the "Unknown" level doesn't exist. You have to change the _levels_, not the data.